# How to report on stored procedures without unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

Our SQL project has a huge number of stored procedures that should all be accompanied by a unit test.

I'm trying to write some Powershell to report on stored procedures that aren't accompanied by a unit test.

Finding the list of stored procedures is trivial - checking they have a test, not so simple. The code seems to be stored in resource files.

This is what I have so far:

```
$sps = ((gci -recurse -include *.sql | select-string "CREATE PROCEDURE") -split ':' | select-string "CREATE PROCEDURE" | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "CREATE PROCEDURE ", ""}) -split " " | select-string "\."

foreach ($sp in $sps)
{

Write-Host  $sp

#ToDo: For each stored procedure, report on a count of EXEC statements calling this procedure in .resx files

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much ado (my Powershell-fu sucks), I've come up with this:

```
# Only include stored procedures that are in the project files
$prjs = (gci -recurse -include *.sqlproj) | select fullname | select-string ":"

foreach ($prj in $prjs)
{
    $file = ($prj -Replace "@{FullName=","") -Replace "}",""        
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
    $used = (((($xml.Project.ItemGroup.Build) | select Include) -split "\\") | select-string ".sql") -replace "}",""    
}

# Pull a list of SPs from the project code
$sps = ((gci -recurse -include $used | select-string "CREATE PROC") -split ':' | select-string "CREATE PROC" | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "CREATE PROCEDURE ", ""} | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "CREATE PROC ", ""}) -split " " | select-string "\."


$fails = 0
$passes = 0

foreach ($sp in $sps)
{   
    # Handle disparity in presentation between [schema].[SpName] between SP and test code    
    $sp2 = ($sp -Replace "\[", "") -Replace "\]", ""    

    # Count each SP name presentation in test code
    $valium1 = (gci -recurse -include *.resx | select-string -SimpleMatch $sp).count
    $valium2 = (gci -recurse -include *.resx | select-string -SimpleMatch $sp2).count

    # If we don't have a match for either presentation, then no test exists
    if ($valium1 -eq 0 -AND $valium2 -eq 0)
    {
        $fails++;
        Write-Host "***FAIL***" $sp
    }
    else
    {
        $passes++;
        Write-Host "***PASS***" $sp  
    }
}

$total = [int]$fails + [int]$passes

Write-Host
Write-Host "Passes: " $passes
Write-Host "Fails : " $fails
Write-Host "------------"
Write-Host "Total : " $total
Write-Host "------------"
```